# Can I get the client's IP address in an LCDS service call?

Tags: apache-flex, lcds

I'm trying to find the IP address of a client when they make a particular LCDS service call.  Understanding all the issues of getting a "real" IP address and privacy concerns and so on, it is possible to find the client's IP address?

tj

Answer (score 1):

I think you can get hold of it pretty easily.
Not tested, but give it a try.

```
String ip = FlexContext.getHttpRequest().getRemoteAddr();
```

Comment: I think that will work for certain kinds of channels, but it doesn't appear to work for RTMP channels.  The HTTP request object is null.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find a way how to do it for all channel types with a simple method call. 
So I use such code:

```
    String ip;
    Endpoint clientEndpoint = FlexContext.getEndpoint();
    if (clientEndpoint instanceof RTMPEndpoint) {
       ip = ((RTMPFlexSession)FlexContext.getFlexSession()).getClientInfo().getIp();  
    }
    if ((clientEndpoint instanceof NIOAMFEndpoint) || (clientEndpoint instanceof AMFEndpoint)) {
       ip = FlexContext.getHttpRequest().getRemoteAddr();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**ip = FlexContext.getHttpRequest().getRemoteAddr();**

is gives whoz connected

Thanks Roman