# How can I retrieve a client's hostname using Flex?

Tags: java, apache-flex, blazeds, hostname

I am building a Flex application which communicates with a Java server using BlazeDS.

What would be the best way to go about making the server aware of the client's hostname?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't determine the client's hostname from within Flex and it's not possible with JavaScript either. However, you can try to lookup the hostname on the server side using a reverse DNS lookup.

First, you'll need to determine the client's IP address. Take a look at "[Can I get the client's IP address in an LCDS service call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352751/can-i-get-the-clients-ip-address-in-an-lcds-service-call)" for an example on how  to do it in BlazeDS.

In order to get the hostname you need to execute a [reverse DNS lookup](http://www.oreillynet.com/onjava/blog/2005/11/reverse_dns_lookup_and_java.html) for the IP address. Please keep in mind that not every IP address has a hostname that can be determined throug reverse DNS lookups.